# Jetty server started but not able to hit the apis

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jetty, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to create a spring webflux application (java 17) which is expected to: -

1. Listen to sqs events and do some processing. (Working fine)
2. Respond to some configured apis. (Not working).

From the logs I could see that the server has started.

```
2023-12-09 10:24:10.537  INFO 69447 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer  : Jetty started on port(s) 11060 (http/1.1) with context path '/'
```

Now when I make a request (curl --location 'localhost:11060/api/get'), I get the below 404 error:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /api/get. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The logs from the server after the request are as follows:

```
https://pastebin.com/JsW5Azu1
```

This is my rest controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RestApi {
    @GetMapping("/get")
    public String get(){
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local
server:
  port: 11060

management:
    port: 11061
    security:
      enabled: false
```

application-local.yml

```
server:
  port: 11060

logging:
  level:
    root: DEBUG
    org:
      springframework: DEBUG
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
        (exclude = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(S3Configuration.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "in.name.consumers.*",
        "in.name.consumers.controller.*",
})
@EnableSqsWithRetry
public class NameConsumer {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(NameConsumer.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
https://pastebin.com/A9SrDGNN
```

I only need the api for health check.

I have added actuator dependency but even that is not working.

I have been stuck on this for days now. Need some help around this.

Comment: why have you excluded `EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration` if you cant get things to work, why not start out by removing all the strange custom things and get something standard working first?

Comment: Yup. Started everything from scratch and it worked. In my pom i added spring-boot-starter-parent. Also i was trying out this new feature as a sub module in an existing project. Which might have created some issues. Moved out the this module to diff project all together and things started working without any change except for the parent. 
Thanks @Toerktumlare